# Animating using CSS instead of a gif with looping

Tags: css, css-animations

I just want to basically show text and hide, then next text and hide, then last text and hide and repeat. How can I do this? I've been looking at code but I'm still lost. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My Code :

```
<style>
  #myArea {
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
  }

  .text {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:20px; 
    left:10px;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div id="myArea">
    <img src="images/backgrnd.jpg" />
    <div id="txt1" class="text">
      <img src="images/text1.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="txt2" class="text">
      <img src="images/text2.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="txt3" class="text">
      <img src="images/text3.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you probably looking for the `steps` timing-function? It provides a gif-like way to animate an image set!

there is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/

from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function

Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting view on the question. Suggesting `steps` sounds logical but it wouldn't produce the same effect when applied on multiple elements. It works best with sprites and a single element. While using multiple elements, the keyframes have to be coded in such a way that the rest remain hidden when one is animating. (*I am not deriding your answer but just stating the obvious for OP's benefit*)

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple to achieve the effect that you are looking for. All that is needed is for you to place the images absolutely on top of each other and then add an animation which changes the `opacity` of the image (or its container) accordingly.

The key parts when animating multiple elements in a loop are to

- make sure that the animation of the second and subsequent elements start after all the previous elements have completed their animation and
- make sure all the previous elements stay in the final state until the other elements complete their animation (otherwise they will mess up the animation).

The first part can be achieved by using progressive `animation-delay` on elements while the second part is achieved by setting the `@keyframes` accordingly. Here, since there are 3 images, animation of each of them should be completed at 33% mark itself (because during the other 66%, the other 2 will be executing their animation). The state as at 33% should be maintained till 100%.

(*If you have 4 images, it should complete at 25% and so on.*)

```css
#myArea {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in-out 9s ease backwards infinite 1s; /* initial delay is for image to load */
}
.text:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s; /* this must start after first has faded-out */
}
.text:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 7s; /* this must start after second has also faded-out */
}
@keyframes fade-in-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  11%, 22% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myArea">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/abstract/2" />
  <div id="txt1" class="text">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/1" />
  </div>
  <div id="txt2" class="text">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/2" />
  </div>
  <div id="txt3" class="text">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, as always. It's useful in this kind of animations to set the delays to negative values. It helps make sure that all the cycles of the animation work the same

Comment: Thank you @vals. Understood "what" you are suggesting to change but not much the "why". Is there any article or link where I can read more about it? If yes please share and I'll have a look tomorrow morning :)

Comment: I don't have a reference at hand that I can share... But I have seen a couple of questions about animations saying "my animation is ok the first time, but wrong on the second iteration" Usually, if you set positive animation delays, the initial state is important. But if you set negative delays, **only** the animation properties are used. Will try to find an example :-)

Comment: Ah ok, I think I got you. Generally during the delay period, the default properties (set outside of keyframes) will apply for an element until the delay timer is elapsed. When you set delay as negative, the timer has already elapsed at start itself. The other way is to add `animation-fill-mode: backwards`. The backwards setting takes care of it because it makes the element take the properties as at the first keyframe during the delay period also :)